# Geometric Distribution: 3 Heads.

Tags: statistics

Tossing a biased coin where $P($Head$)=0.3$, $P($Tail$)=0.7$

I know $P($1st Head Appears After 5 Tosses$)=(0.7)^5$ because first 5 tosses cannot be heads.

What about $P($3rd Head Appears After 5 Tosses$)$?

Answer (score 0):

It is the probability $P(H\leq2)$ where $H$ denotes the number of heads that show up among the first $5$ tosses.

Here $H$ evidently has binomial distribution with parameters $n=5$ and $p=0.3$.

Comment: Are you sure? Couldn't all 3 heads appear after 5 Tosses and still satisfy "3rd head appears after 5 tosses?" Or 1st head appear within the first 5 tosses, 2nd and 3rd head appear after 5 tosses?

Comment: Sure. That is the event $\{H=0\}\subseteq\{H\leq2\}$. And the second you menstion is $\{H=1\}\subseteq\{H\leq2\}$. Third hat *after* first $5$ tosses is the same as:at most $2$ hats *within* first $5$ tosses (so that among them is not the third hat).